# Error smach_viewer in ROS noetic

Tags: ros, ubuntu, python3, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I read the smach tutorial and there is no problem until I run smach_viewer command.
[Smach tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials/Smach%20Viewer)
`rosrun smach_viewer smach_viewer.py`

The terminal shows the below error :
`[rospack] Error: package 'smach_viewer' not found`

I checked the */opt/ros/noetic/share* path there is no smach_viewer package. just smach.
the question is: **What should I do to see the graphical representation of my smach code?**

I'm using ubuntu focal, Noetic ROS, and python3.
thanks a lot for your support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403376/error-smach_viewer-in-ros-noetic/) by [Morteza7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106029/morteza7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems Smach lib is based on Python2 and ROS noetic is not supported by python2. So the lib of the Smach should change to Python3.

---

Originally posted by [Morteza7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106029/morteza7/) with karma: 31 on 2022-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0